# ms-gamingoverlay required when I open Google Chrome's Incognito - Windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, xbox-game-dvr

I always prefer to use Incognito mode when I open Google maps. Today, my computer started lagging which never happens, although, multiple IDEs were open, but, I checked and it was a service called `game dvr and broadcast user`, it was using 70% of the CPU and yes, I had just opened an incog window.

I looked it up and it was related to X-Box game bar so, I uninstalled it using Iobit's uninstaller as the option in Windows' app settings was greyed out.

Now, I've just noticed after uninstalling it, whenever I open Google Chrome's incog window, this dialog appears as you can see in the screenshots.

I've already tried disabling every extension I've, not some shady ones, 5 popular ones for Adblock, Youtube etc.

Is this spyware? Should I be afraid of it? I already have the premium anti-virus with proper license provided by our company, which I actually trust and I really don't want to reset Google chrome.

[image]

Comment: "Is this spyware?" -  It absolutely postively Is NOT spyware; My suggestion would be to uninstall Chrome and then reinstall it in order to resolve the file extension association issue you have

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for that, uninstall is the only option I see, so, I'll do it. But, do you know why this happened or why is it a file extension related issue? It seems it has nothing to do with Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by using an uninstaller.

Try this for a solution :

- Run *Settings > Gaming > Xbox Game Bar*
- Disable the option named
  "Record game clips, screenshots, and broadcast using Game bar"
- If using Windows 11, navigate to *Settings > Gaming > Captures*
  and disable all recording options
- A reboot might be required.

Comment: The author already removed the Xbox Game Bar. Have you confirmed your instructions are applicable to Windows 10? How does the author follow these instructions if the application has already been removed

Comment: @Ramhound: That's my suspicion - that the application was removed but is still being solicited. That's what seems to be happening.

Comment: Yes, I've already uninstalled Game bar considerign it was faulty. But, the problem still persists, for now, I cannot afford to reinstall chrome so I've just ignored it.